# Google maps 2 destination fields

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am creating a web page that has two textboxes and a get directions button. When the button is pressed, a route is traced between the two locations. This works very well.

The problem is this: After I have pressed the button once and I enter new locations, the new route is not displayed when the button is pressed.

Here is a link to my code:

http://www.canning.co.nz/Mapping/Code.txt

Here is a link to a working example (to show you what I mean in my above description):

http://canning.co.nz/Mapping/directions.html

EDIT

I also see that the Gload() function is the function that sets the variables for the two and from destination textbox fields. So in the getDirections() function I have placed a call to the GLoad() function. However, still no luck.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`gdir` is not a global variable. You define it in `function doEnd()` with `var`, which makes it local to that function and not available elsewhere.

Make `gdir` a global variable by including

```
var gdir;
```

outside any function, and then simply use that variable inside `doEnd()` by omitting the `var`.

You also use the variable `search` a number of times in different contexts, and at least one of those should be global: there is an error **`search is not defined`** in `function searchFunc()` at

```
var result=geo.getCache().get(search);
```

You will need to sort out your use of that variable name. It's not really good practice to use the same variable name in different functions because it makes it easy to assume a global variable when it's been defined as local.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I have modified it as you suggested, yet it still is not working.

Comment: Please post a link to the NOT working page. It's not easy debugging a code listing.

Comment: The funny thing is, if I set new values in the textboxes, and reload the page, the new values stay in the textboxes and then the getdirections button works... this situation may help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Answer updated. I didn't mean you to overwrite your working version: uploading the non-working version alongside it (with a different name) would have sufficed, especially since there is a major issue with variable scope and usage.

Comment: OK, so can you please explain what I should do about the: var result=geo.getCache().get(search); line of code. Maybe even create a working html for me to look at if you have the time. :)

Comment: No, I can't, or I would have done already. You need to sort out your use of the `search` variable: which ones need to be local, and which shared between functions. I suggest you don't have more than one `search`. I can't tell which is which.

Comment: The search variables seem to only be loaded in via the GLoad() function. So it seems that I should just refresh this function with new values in the textboxes. However, when I do this, it just doesn't work.